# Disconnect and close serial port from console so I can use it in my application

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel

Ubuntu 16.04

I need /dev/ttyS0 (serial port) for use in my application.

Command:

```
~$ dmesg | grep tty
```

Response with:

```
[    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
[    0.691609] 00:05: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[    0.715333] 00:06: ttyS1 at I/O 0x2f8 (irq = 3, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
```

How do I close the serial port (for current session only is also ok) so I can use it for my own needs?

Comment: What application is using the serial port?  How do you know you can't use it?

Comment: for instance I'm trying to open the port (/dev/ttyS0) using PuTTY and it fails with message "unable to open serial port"

Comment: Thanks @drewbenn your comment solved the issue. I added my self to the dialout group and it work like a charm